# Can i use RDkit with pure python3 in Windows OS

Tags: python-3.x, rdkit

I want to use RDkit with python3 in windows OS

But here are something I got confused

Besides the author said the most recommend way is anaconda(I don't want this),the other way is to install RDkit with release binary package. But as I follow  the document as BELLOW:

Get the appropriate windows binary build from: https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/releases

Extract the zip file somewhere without a space in the name, i.e. C:\

The rest of this will assume that the installation is in C:\RDKit_2015_09_2

Set the following environment variables:

RDBASE: C:\RDKit_2015_09_2

PYTHONPATH: %RDBASE% if there is already a PYTHONPATH, put ;%RDBASE% at the end.

PATH: add ;%RDBASE%\lib to the end

I do got the latest releases

I unzip the package

But the directory doesn't have the sub dir name "lib" in last step: **PATH: add ;%RDBASE%\lib to the end**

What can I do? do I mkdir named lib at there? Or just the binary package is not full?

besides, if i want to use compile source code way,the example enviroment is python2.7,can i compile it with python3?

Answer (score 0):

i have fix this problem

the result i put on [my github](https://github.com/hookery/rdkit)